# Blender, and it's relationship with VRam and virtual video memory

Tags: animation

My PC has no dedicated video memory and due to this my blender freezes sometimes when I am using it. My question is, can increasing my virtual memory help with the occasional freezing of the software?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that inside of blender , in the software you can only adjust the rendering settings : samples , lights , shadow reflections , caustics , texture resolution etc.. to increase performance and lower memory usage .

To increase RAM dedication to VRAM you need to do that outside blender , i think it's in the bios settings or something like that , there are plenty of tutorials on how to do that ( videos , articles .. ) . Look on how to dedicate more RAM to VRAM on google and you'll find a way .

Good luck !